# how to use pyro to call python with object as parameter

Tags: java, python, pyro

I have setup a small test java application that calls a python script after starting a pyro server (in python).  It works great except now I want to pass the python class an object as a parameter to its method.  I get an exception from the python side saying:

```
Pyro4.errors.SerializeError: unsupported serialized class: 
com.test.pyro4.TestLog
```

According to pyros documentation a class will get converted to a dict in python but I can't even get that far.

java code:

```
NameServerProxy ns = NameServerProxy.locateNS("localhost");
PyroProxy remotePluginObject = new PyroProxy(ns.lookup("plugin"));

int length = 5;
double[] values = new double[] { 0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 05, 0.4 };
double a = 6.94;
double b = 2.17;

remoteObject = new PyroProxy(ns.lookup("test.object"));
remoteObject.call("setValues", values, length);

Object result = remoteObject.call("calculate", remoteObject, a, b);

System.out.println(result.toString());

remotePluginObject.close();             
remoteObject.close();
ns.close();
```

python server code:

```
class TestObject(object):
values=[]
length=0

def setValues(self, valuesArray, lengthValue):
    values=valuesArray
    length=lengthValue    

class Plugin(object):
def calculate(self, obj, a, b):
    result = example.calculate(obj, a, b)
    return result

plugin=Plugin()
obj=TestObject()

daemon=Pyro4.Daemon()
ns=Pyro4.locateNS()

pluginURI=daemon.register(plugin)
ns.register("plugin", pluginURI)

objURI=daemon.register(obj)
ns.register("test.object", objURI)

daemon.requestLoop()
```

Comment: code has been updated to show how it now works.  object is created on python side and then its requested via proxy on java side, values set, and then used in call to python method.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  Above code does not work.  Gets the following error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.  I have stripped out all prameters from call to python leaving just the object and it appears to be something with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the serializer to `pickle`:

```
Pyro4.config.SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
```

Be aware that this has [security implications](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/security.html?highlight=security).

And this in Java:

```
Config.SERIALIZER = Config.SerializerType.pickle;
```

Comment: same error, is there a certian place this needs to be?  I added it just before the print of the uri

Comment: Put it at the very first line and re-start everything.

Comment: I now get an error that is too long to paste in but says this on one line:    Pyro4.errors.SerializeError: message used serializer that is not accepted: 4.  This happens when starting the server and not when trying to call the method from java

Comment: checking the config its accepted serializers are serpent, marshal, and json.  its using serpent currently which is what it should also be doing on the java side as thats the jar I have on my classpath

Comment: added pickle to set of serializers and tried above but still get same error

Comment: Where does `com.test.pyro4.TestLog `com from?

Comment: thats the java class I am trying to pass to the python side

Comment: Did you try with primitve types like int? Does it work?

Comment: I am using pyrolite on the java side.  I have tried it with primitives and arrays and it works great, just not with my own objects.

Comment: Did you try turning on pickle on the Java side? See my modification of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77810/discussion-between-mike-muller-and-user1584120).